# Redirect a checkbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have the html and css of a cool switch box and I will use it as a language switch on my website. However, as I am a beginner in JavaScript, I am missing the handler that would do the redirect thing.

Here's is my work so far. The problem is in the JavaScript.

```js
 $(".flag-switch input").click(function(){$(this).is(":checked")?setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="en/"},250):setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="../"},250)}
```

```css
.flag-switch {
    position: relative;
    right: -30px;
    top: 4px;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.flag-switch:before, .flag-switch:after {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    top: 8px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.flag-switch:before {
    left: -19px;
    content: attr(data-first-lang);
}
.flag-switch:after {
    right: -17px;
    content: attr(data-second-lang);
}
.flag-switch input {
    display: none;
}
.flag-switch input + label {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    width: 60px;
}
.flag-switch input + label:before, .flag-switch input + label:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.flag-switch input + label:before {
    height: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color:#EE4B53 ;
}
.flag-switch input + label:after {
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #DFDFDF;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: #eb3 url(http://i.imgur.com/mYEJa6E.png) -26px center;
    transform: translate(30px, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(30px, 0);
}
.flag-switch input:checked + label:after {
    background: #000233 url(http://i.imgur.com/mYEJa6E.png) -2px center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.flag-switch input:checked + label:before {
    background-color: #1FA9D6;
}
```

```html
  <div class="flag-switch" data-first-lang="GR" data-second-lang="EN">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" checked>
    <label for="check1"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: `$` that is not vanilla JavaScript, that's jQuery

Comment: Yes, but can i do it vanilla JavaScript? I saw some methods but they did not work.

Comment: In the above snippet you have forgotten to add `jquery.min.js`.

Comment: FYI: http://flagsarenotlanguages.com/blog/why-flags-do-not-represent-language/

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, i use it for only two languages so i don't believe that's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript version of the same:

```js
document.querySelector('#check1').addEventListener('change', function(){
 if(this.checked){
   setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="en/"},250);
  }
  else{
    setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="../"},250);
  }  
});
```

```css
.flag-switch {
  position: relative;
    right: -30px;
    top: 4px;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
.flag-switch:before, .flag-switch:after {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  top: 8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.flag-switch:before {
  left: -19px;
  content: attr(data-first-lang);
}
.flag-switch:after {
  right: -17px;
  content: attr(data-second-lang);
}
.flag-switch input {
  display: none;
}
.flag-switch input + label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  width: 60px;
}
.flag-switch input + label:before, .flag-switch input + label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.flag-switch input + label:before {
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color:#EE4B53 ;
}
.flag-switch input + label:after {
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #DFDFDF;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: #eb3 url(http://i.imgur.com/mYEJa6E.png) -26px center;
  transform: translate(30px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(30px, 0);
}
.flag-switch input:checked + label:after {
  background: #000233 url(http://i.imgur.com/mYEJa6E.png) -2px center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.flag-switch input:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #1FA9D6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flag-switch" data-first-lang="GR" data-second-lang="EN">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" >
    <label for="check1"></label>
</div>
```